# After embedding a navigationController into a tabBarController, the tabBarItem area disappears in interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I'm using Xcode 7.0.1.

After embedding a `UINavigationController` into a `UITabBarController` in a storyboard, the area for `tabBarItem`s gets replaced by a big bottom bar and is not editable even after I add another connection from the `tabBarController` to a second `UIViewController`.

So, can anyone let me know how to fix the `tabBarItem` area to make it visible. See the image below:
[image: Attached Picture of the tab bar controller I get with no tab bar item]

I tried playing around with simulated metrics after checking around here for similar issues, but without luck.

Comment: How did it behave before? Undo?

Comment: This is my first usage/creation of tab bar controller. So the very first time of usage, I'm getting this issue. Tried re-creating tab bar controller embedding to navigation controller, but did not work.

Comment: It might depend on what you've connected your `UITabBarController` to. Is it embedded in a container or where is the segue pointing to it coming from?

Comment: UITabBarController is embedded in a navigation container. I was able to click and change tabBarItems now, only by selecting from dropdown option in the storyBoard of navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click and change tabBarItems now, only by selecting from dropdown option in the storyBoard of navigation controller.